# Making a new object, cannot be applied to type (int)

Tags: java

I have a ProcessHeap class that has two fields:

*Heap*: an array of type Process which represents the heap

*Size*: the number of elements in the heap

My constructor and attributes look like this:

```
private Process[] heap;
private int size;
private static int counter = 0;

//Paramaterized construct
    public ProcessHeap(Process[] heap, int size) {
        this.heap = heap;
        this.size = size;
```

The problem is, we were given a driver and at the start of the driver I am getting an error particularly on `(HEAP_SIZE)`

This is the line:

```
final int HEAP_SIZE = 100;
ProcessHeap heap = new ProcessHeap(HEAP_SIZE); // gives this error:
```

The error upon mouse-over states:

> ProcessHeap (Process[], int) in ProcessHeap cannot be applied to (int)

Comment: you have a constructor `ProcessHeap(Process[] heap, int size)` but try to call it here `new ProcessHeap(HEAP_SIZE)` with only an int - so the compiler stops and warns you that the parameters do not match up

Comment: You havent `public ProcessHeap(int n)` constructor.

Comment: @ChristopherMilelr if your question is answered, please mark it as such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said; your direct problem is that you want only have one constructor taking two arguments, but then you are invoking it with **one** argument. But beyond that, you are over-complicating things:

```
class ProcessHeap {
  private final Process[] heap;

 public ProcessHeap(int size) {
   heap = new Process[size];
 }
```

is all that you **need** and **should** use. There is no point in tracking size and array in two places. You can always do `heap.length` to get the size of your heap. And beyond that: you absolutely do **not** want that users of this class have to provide an array for your heap - because they could just go and manipulate that array later on.

Your class implements that heap; and that you are using an array to do that is an implementation detail that you should **not at all** communicate to the outside world.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor ProcessHeap is taking 2 parameters (an array and an integer), you are passing only one...

So you need either to change the params in the constructor:

`ProcessHeap(Process[] heap, int size)`  and remove the arraay, OR overload it defining a new one taking only an integer.

Answer (score 0):

**In your `ProcessHeap` class, you don't have a constructor which takes `int` argument**, so declare it as shown below:

```
public class ProcessHeap {

   private int heapSize;

    public ProcessHeap(int heapSize) {
      this.heapSize = heapSize;
    }

    //your other existing code

}
```

Comment: that wouldn't go along with what the ProcessHeap is supposed to do, at least the constructor should initialize the process array

Comment: Exactly. This answer is technically correct, but doesn't make any sense regarding the context.

Answer (score 0):

### the problem

you have a constructor `ProcessHeap(Process[] heap, int size)` but try to call it here `new ProcessHeap(HEAP_SIZE)` with only an int - so the compiler stops and warns you that the parameters do not match up

### how to fix it?

you either have to change the constructor/add a constructor, which I guess you can't, cause its for your assignment

the other option is that you pass an already created array of processes

```
final int HEAP_SIZE = 100;

final Process[] processHeap = new Process[HEAP_SIZE];

ProcessHeap heap = new ProcessHeap(processHeap , HEAP_SIZE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define one parameter `constructor` also because you are passing only single`Integer` value. At the time of Instantiate the `ProcessHeap` class.

```
    private Process[] heap;
    private int size;
    private static int counter = 0;

    //One Paramaterized construct 
     public ProcessHeap( int size) {
            this.size = size;
     }

    //Two Paramaterized construct
     public ProcessHeap(Process[] heap, int size) {
            this.heap = heap;
            this.size = size;
     }
```

Now you cal call your `Constructor` As you desired.

**Like  This**

```
final int HEAP_SIZE = 100;

final Process[] processHeap = new Process[HEAP_SIZE];

ProcessHeap heap = new ProcessHeap(HEAP_SIZE); 
ProcessHeap heap1 = new ProcessHeap(processHeap , HEAP_SIZE);
```